# Не работает file_get_contents из-за pynecode

Tags: php

Следующая ошибка:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://vapi.домен.xn--p1ai/PrivateAPI/123): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Код:

```
    $file1 = file_get_contents("http://vapi.xn--d1acufc.xn--p1ai/PrivateAPI/123");
```

Comment: А это $file1 = file_get_contents('h t t p://www.yandex.ru/'); ошибку выдаст?

Comment: "h t t p" так написано, потому что парсер съедает ссылкой.

Comment: проверял на google.com, там было просто 404

Comment: Вероятно, ваш DNS не знает куда запрос с таким именем домена отправить. Потрясите своего хостера по этому вопросу. Или вы на локалхосте ошибку получаете?

Comment: На локалхосте то как раз все нормально

Comment: Тогда хостера спросить стоит, почему его DNS не знает такого сайта ;)

Comment: Спасибо, я изменил на гугл паблик днс, заработало :). Преобразуйте коммент в ответ :).